# Button animation while pressed

Tags: qt, qml

still quite new in QML.
What I wish to do (and could not find out it on google) is to have background animation (like progress bar, green color moving from left to right in interval od 2sec = onMyPressAndHold).
So far all is working, i have to hold button for 2 sec otherwise nothing happens... during this period of holding the button I would like to have the background button of progress bar moving (filling) from left to right...
So far tried few things i googled up, but no luck at all.

```
Button {
    id: stopButton
    text: 'STOP' // STOP
    width: parent.width
    height: 50

    anchors {
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    signal myPressAndHold()

    onPressed: {
        pressAndHoldTimer.start();
    }
    onReleased: {
        pressAndHoldTimer.stop();
    }
    onMyPressAndHold: {
        stopButton.text = 'PLEASE WAIT...';
        textProgress.text = 'STOPPED';
        elapsedTimer.stop();
        DatabaseJS.push_start(mainScreen);
    }

    Timer {
        id: pressAndHoldTimer
        interval: 2000
        running: false
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            parent.myPressAndHold();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no animation implementation. And so if you say _So far all is working_ what your question is?

Comment: honestly this is all i got... i had some unsuccesfull tests which i decided to delete as it seemed it doesnt even make sence to work... and I was not able to google anythimg similar to start with... so my question is, how to even begin, and hopefully how to finish the animation to final state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to reproduce the behavior of an already existing item [`DelayButton`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-qtquick-controls2-delaybutton.html):

```
DelayButton {
    text: progress > 0 ? 'PLEASE WAIT...' : 'STOP'
    delay: 2000
    background: Rectangle {
        // here you can define your background, bound to your button 'progress' value
        // ...
    }

    onActivated: DatabaseJS.push_start(mainScreen)
}
```